# How linked/shared legend with pie and column?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

If we take this exemple : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo

How can I shared legend between pie and column? I want to aviable/disable one serie when I click on legend for column AND pie in same time !

Answer (score 0):

Bind `legendItemClick` event and there hide connected slices in the pie chart. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x8ygvwbx/1/

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(e) {
                    var vis = this.visibility,
                        name = this.name,
                        pie = this.chart.get("my-pie"), // set pie's ID
                        index = pie.options.legendNames.indexOf(name); // get index of names

                    pie.points[index].setVisible(vis); //change visibility
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

And example for pie options:

```
    {
        id: "my-pie",  // ID
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Total consumption',
        legendNames: ["Jane", "John", "Joe"], //NAMES
        data: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            y: 13,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            y: 23,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            y: 19,
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
        }]
    }
```